# why my ubuntu 18.04 have many dev/loop? and how to fix it?

Tags: 18.04

When I run df in the terminal, there are many dev/loops. It looks weird and anoying a bit. I would like to ask how to fix this? Thanks!

```
 ~ $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             5972388        0   5972388   0% /dev
tmpfs            1198968     2084   1196884   1% /run
/dev/sda8       92165144 18667112  69539428  22% /
tmpfs            5994840   476084   5518756   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            5994840        0   5994840   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         99456    99456         0 100% /snap/core/9993
/dev/loop1         63616    63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop3          2560     2560         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop2         56704    56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/loop5           384      384         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/570
/dev/loop7        223232   223232         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop6          1024     1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop8          2304     2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop4        144128   144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100
tmpfs            1198968       20   1198948   1% /run/user/122
tmpfs            1198968       80   1198888   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop9        148096   148096         0 100% /snap/zoom-client/101
/dev/loop10       184064   184064         0 100% /snap/skype/153
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a bin directory in your $HOME, which is before the system directories in your PATH environment variable. To override the system df, you can make a script named "df" in your $HOME/bin directory with the contents:

```
cd $HOME/bin
echo '/bin/df $@ |grep -v "loop.*snap/"' >df
chmod +x df
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of default-installed components, including GNOME 3 and Snap/Ubuntu Core components, are packaged as Snaps now.  Snaps all get their base data mounted on `/dev/loop` devices, and unfortunately there is no way to 'remove' the loops.

Unfortunately, this is just how things are now that there's more heavy reliance on Snaps for serving updates and patches to GNOME components and some other things (like Zoom and Skype which you installed yourself from the Software Center, it defaulted to Snaps for those)